# AutowareAuto 1.0.0 build failed with xsens_nodes and euclidean_cluster

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learnning ROS2 and AutowareAuto due to a recent project.  I follow the setps on [the offcial website](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/usage.html) and install autoware.auto without ade. Some problems appear when building using "colcon build" command.

**problem 1**
--- stderr: xsens_nodes
In file included from /home/minphie/AutowareAuto/src/drivers/xsens_nodes/src/xsens_imu_node.cpp:17:
/home/minphie/AutowareAuto/src/drivers/xsens_nodes/include/xsens_nodes/xsens_imu_node.hpp:28:10: fatal error: serial_driver/serial_driver_node.hpp: No such file or directory
28 | #include "serial_driver/serial_driver_node.hpp"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Failed   <<< xsens_nodes [0.27s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< autoware_auto_msgs [3.76s]
Aborted  <<< rosapi [1.29s]
Summary: 28 packages finished [4.50s]
1 package failed: xsens_nodes
2 packages aborted: autoware_auto_msgs rosapi
1 package had stderr output: xsens_nodes
62 packages not processed

I read the source code and get that xsens_nodes package depends on serial_drvier package.  Next,  I find the ros-foxy-serial-driver is installed but installed include path "/opt/ros/foxy/include/serial_driver"  doesn't contain the file "serial_driver/serial_driver_node.hpp＂. There are serial_bridge_node.hpp  serial_port.hpp
serial_driver.hpp       visibility_control.hpp.

**problem 2**---stderr: euclidean_cluster

The problem 1 is not resolved, but I plan to ignore it bucause I don't need xsens driver and nodes packages.
I copy COLCON_IGNORE file to the both packages so that colcon build will pass xsens driver and nodes packages.

Unfortunately, new problem appeared like this:
/home/minphie/AutowareAuto/src/perception/segmentation/euclidean_cluster/include/euclidean_cluster/euclidean_cluster.hpp:89:36: error: ‘clusters’ is not a member of ‘autoware::perception::segmentation::euclidean_cluster::Clusters’ {aka ‘autoware_auto_msgs::msg::PointClusters_std::allocator<void >’}
89 | using Cluster = decltype(Clusters::clusters)::value_type;

...

Failed   <<< euclidean_cluster [19.8s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< off_map_obstacles_filter [1min 14s]
Aborted  <<< localization_nodes [47.7s]
Aborted  <<< voxel_grid [26.0s]
Aborted  <<< controller_common [27.0s]
Aborted  <<< trajectory_smoother [22.9s]
Aborted  <<< vehicle_interface [1min 37s]
Aborted  <<< had_map_utils [1min 41s]

Summary: 38 packages finished [1min 47s]
1 package failed: euclidean_cluster
7 packages aborted: controller_common had_map_utils localization_nodes off_map_obstacles_filter trajectory_smoother vehicle_interface voxel_grid
3 packages had stderr output: euclidean_cluster had_map_utils rosapi
45 packages not processed

---

**My soft environment**

Uubuntu 20.04 LTS

ROS2 foxy  full-desktop installed from debian package

Autoware Auto Tag 1.00 (Relase 1.0.0)   built outside ade

**My hardware**

Intel I7 16G RAM

---

Looking forward to your guidance, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389543/autowareauto-1.0.0-build-failed-with-xsens_nodes-and-euclidean_cluster/) by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/84773/maxime/) on 2021-10-31**:
Within the ADE environment I am able to build the `1.0.0` tag without issue (commit `a6177a215956a73e75fc12abc02178b1c957d14a`).
For **problem 1**, you can try to run the following in the `AutowareAuto` folder:

- `sudo apt update`.
- `rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO`.

For **problem 2**, the issue might be coming from `autoware_auto_msgs` which is an "external" repository. Did you run `vcs import < autoware.auto.foxy.repos` in the `AutowareAuto` folder ?

**Comment by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on 2021-11-01**:
I have tried running `rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO`  and get that `#All required rosdeps installed successfully`. I think it's the version of the library because I get similar problem when building velodyne_nodes:

--- stderr: velodyne_nodes
In file included from /home/minphie/AutowareAuto/src/drivers/velodyne_nodes/src/velodyne_cloud_node.cpp:24:
/home/minphie/AutowareAuto/src/drivers/velodyne_nodes/include/velodyne_nodes/velodyne_cloud_node.hpp:30:10: fatal error: udp_driver/udp_driver_node.hpp: No such file or directory
30 | #include "udp_driver/udp_driver_node.hpp"

For **problem 2**, I have ran `vcs import < autoware.auto.foxy.repos`  and there is an "external" folder in the `~/AutowareAuto/src` folder.

**Comment by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on 2021-11-01**:
The ros  seral_driver and udp_driver are both intalled and the information is as follows:

Package: **ros-foxy-serial-driver**
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 666
Maintainer: Joshua Whitley whitleysoftwareservices@gmail.com
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0.0-1focal.20210901.193835

Package: **ros-foxy-udp-driver**
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 794
Maintainer: Joshua Whitley whitleysoftwareservices@gmail.com
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.0.0-1focal.20210901.193301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sure the problems come from the version of seral_driver and udp_driver packages. They are newest version (1.0.0) in my computer. I clone the repo https://github.com/ros-drivers/transport_drivers and checkt out 0.0.6. Move `udp_driver` and `serial_driver` to `~/AutowareAuto/src/driver` then colcon build successfully.

---

Originally posted by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) with karma: 13 on 2021-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1